# Multiple tab rows for Firefox 57

Tags: gratis, firefox

I usually have dozens of tabs open, because I work on many different things.
So I need my tabs on multiple rows (other UI suggestions are OK).

Is there an add-on for this?

- Gratis
- Compatible with Firefox 57
- Ideally open source
- Preferably an addon, but if no addon is available then a patch is OK too

Note: [TabMixPlus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) is currently not compatible with Firefox 57

Comment: Afraid there's a contradiction in terms: FF57 <-> UI modifications. Their new WE API won't allow for that.

Comment: @Izzy If no WebExtension can do that, a patch in the vein of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361535/how-can-i-have-multiple-rows-with-tabs-on-firefox-57-tab-mix-plux-add-on-no-lo suggests could be a solution too.

Comment: Might be a question of time for Moz to turn those `userStyle.css` modifications off as well. I vaguely remember having read something of that. TMP is what I use as well (I did *not* go Quantum, and probably won't, as they broke compatibility with several addons essential to me – TMP being one of them). So those "work arounds" might be quite temporary. As many things are, with Moz.

Comment: I also was using TMP for this reason and ended up going to Tab Center Redux.  You might want to check it out.  It can be customized in different ways (none of which is multiple columns).

Comment: Current workaround is to use [tab center redux](https://github.com/eoger/tabcenter-redux), which displays a list of tabs at the left side as a list.

Answer (score 1):

[**Paxmod**](https://github.com/numirias/paxmod) is Firefox mod/theme with multiple tab rows (and site-dependent tab colors) which I wrote.

> - Gratis

Sure.

> Compatible with Firefox 57

It has been tested in latest FF Nightly (currently  61.0a1).

> Ideally open source

Sure, it's on GitHub.

> Preferably an addon, but if no addon is available then a patch is OK too

It's a WebExtension. However, in order to modify the browser UI it's bundled with an [API experiment](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions/Experiments), an additional unofficial API to apply CSS to the browser UI.

Unfortunately, this means the extension won't be signed by Mozilla and it can't be distributed over the official channels (but you can simply install it from GitHub or build it yourself). Therefore, you also need to run it in either Firefox Developer or Nightly.

As @Izzy noted in a comment, the set of APIs that are available to regular WebExtensions is pretty limited, so you likely won't get UI modifications with any (non-legacy) addon from the store.

Comment: It works great in Nightly! Too bad I could not find an Ubuntu PPA for Firefox Developer.